# how to create one array of values from multidimensional array

Tags: php

Multidimensional array which I get

```
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 6
)
```

I need to create one simple array

```
["2","3","6"]
```

Comment: `$newarray = $otherarray['someindex']['somindex2']`;

Comment: Use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function. But, your example isn't an multidimensional array.

Comment: Currently your two arrays are equal - no need to do anything..

Comment: @mickmackusa It is easier to read `$newarray` than `$otherarray['someindex']['somindex2']`. Although with some research this could have been obtained easily.

Comment: This answer is asking which php function will convert the array's integer values to string values (**if** that's _actually_ what the OP is asking).  The answer is Read The Manual.  For that reason, please delete your question because this is a low value question and php's online manuals are publicly available for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your two arrays are equal and just printed diffrently. The only difference, I could see is, that one array uses strings as values and the other not.

To change this, you could explicitly cast the values with `array_map`.

```
$int_array = array_map(function ($a) {
    return (string) $a;
}, $array);
```

If you just want the values of the array, you should use `array_values`, which returns the values from the array with the keys.

```
$values = array_values($array);
```

Depends on your use case, what you want to use

Answer (score 0):

This isn't multi dimension , this is an associative array in your example, to get the output you show just use `array_values()`:

```
$values = array_values($array);
```